# How do you get the default system font in the .NET compact framework?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, system-font

How can I get the `Font` object for the default system font used by the particular device?  I've noticed that different devices have different resolutions and DPIs, but some of my controls have explicitly defined fonts.  I'd like to be able to get the default system font at runtime (as if I never changed the `Font` property on the control).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked into `System.Drawing.SystemFonts`? I think it may have what you need.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemfonts.aspx

Edit: I just noticed the CF tag. You will need to look at the registry to get the system font information.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms900747.aspx

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to convert the values in the registry into a Font object?  That is, how do you convert the 'Ht' and 'Wt' into appropriate values for the Font constructor?

Comment: Since the Ht is in pixels you would need to convert it:

points = pixels * (72 / dpi)

As far as the Wt, I am not sure. The range of values is pretty wide. You may have to pick a cutoff and say anything below is normal and anything above is bold.